# Test code interactively with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have fairly little experience with Visual Studio but I have to use it for a class.  Is there a way to set a break point and then call methods interactively to test them?  Specifically, I have created a class and I want to test some of its methods without hard coding everything.

Comment: Your search engine broken? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Comment: have you... searched for [visual studio setting breakpoints](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22visual+studio+setting+break+points&oq=%22visual+studio+setting+break+points&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22visual+studio+setting+breakpoints)?

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase the question.  I know how to set a break point.  From there how do I call the method?  Search engine working fine...

Comment: You call the method with code.  then when that code hits the breakpoint it brings you to that code.

Comment: So there was this plugin named [Alive](http://comealive.io/) that did exactly what you're talking about (disclaimer: I received a free copy to review).  But it's no longer available because the team got hired by Microsoft, and whatever Microsoft-flavored version of the feature is not ready yet.

Comment: Visual Studio debugger has an "Immediate" window that you can use to call functions interactively.  But I'm not sure if breakpoints work when the function is called from the immediate window.  Ok I tried it and yes they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your code, put a breakpoint in your `Main()` function.  Run in debugger and when you hit that first breakpoint, you can set breakpoints in whatever function you want to look at, and use the `Immediate` window to call the function, providing whatever arguments you want to test with.

The debugger will stop at any breakpoint inside the function called from the Immediate window, and then you can step through, watch values, change variables, and generally do whatever debugging you desire.

[image]

This works really well with .NET code, somewhat more restricted for native C++ but it probably will still do everything you care about.